# How to return the Primary Key of the newly inserted row using asyncpg?

Tags: asyncpg

I wanted to do something like this:

```
    async with app.pg_pool.acquire() as pg:
        uid = await pg.execute('INSERT INTO users (created, keyed, key, email) '
                               'VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING id',
                               time, time, key, rj['email'])['id']
```

However `Connection.execute` doesn't seem to return anything other than the status:

https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html?highlight=returning#asyncpg.connection.Connection.execute

The question could be otherwise phrased as: How do I get back the response of the `RETURNING` statement when using asyncpg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use [Connection.fetchval()](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html?highlight=returning#asyncpg.connection.Connection.fetchval) instead of `execute()`.

Comment: fetchval for multiple rows/bulk insert?

Answer (score 0):

The `Connection.execute` will return the status of the INSERT. If you need the Record, Records or Value use one of the following instead of `Connection.execute` :

1. `Connection.fetchval` - returns only the value of one field specified. Returns `null` if no fields are specified.
2. `Connection.fetch` - will return an array of `dict`. Each dict will have the list of fields specified after the `RETURNING` statement.
3. `Connection.fetchrow` - will return a `dict` with the list of fields specified after the `RETURNING` statement